# Waiting for output: unexpected behaviour when piping xinput test to grep

Tags: pipe, xinput

After

```
% xkbset -repeatkeys
% xinput test 14 | grep -m 1 "key release 36"
```

and holding the second return, nothing happens, as expected.  After
releasing the second return, I get

```
key release 36
```

Now I would expect the programme to exit immediately, but instead it
waits for an additional keypress---even shift works---, before
exiting.  I suppose this makes xinput produce an additional line, but
I don't see why that should be necessary---grep has already found the
line it was looking for.  So why doesn't it exit immediately?

PS.  The answer seems correct, and I was able to get the desired
result by doing

```
% xinput test 14 | { grep -m 1 "key release 36" && killall xinput ; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` probably does exit after the first match. It's `xinput` that's still running: it only notices the pipe is closed the next time it tries to output something.

For example, here only the first pgrep finds a running `grep` process, but the sleep on the left-hand side still happens.

```
$ ( pgrep grep >&2; echo xxx; pgrep grep >&2; sleep 3; echo yyy ) |grep -m1 xxx
29149
xxx
```